# Validate a list of numbers separated by -

Tags: php, string, validation, numbers

How can I validate a string that contains a list of numbers like:

`23-4-3-3434-356-323`

Any string that matches the pattern `NUMBER-NUMBER-...` is valid.

Comment: What sort of validation?

Comment: like `if(valid($string)) { ... }`

Comment: Well I believe the answer is "regular expressions" but your string doesn't make it clear what a "valid" string looks like.

Comment: list using hyphens as separators? novel

Comment: @Marc any string that doesn't have this pattern NUMBER-NUMBER etc..

Comment: Validate against what? You could explode the string and validate the numbers by themself or use a regular expression to match the complete string. Little more information about the desired result would be nice.

Comment: `preg_match('/[^0-9\-]/', $string)` will match any string which DOESN't consist of only dashes and numbers.

Comment: What's valid or invalid? Is it only valid if it matches that exact string?

Comment: After the edits, this is a valid question so it should  be re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like the regex version then:

```
$valid = true;
foreach(explode('-', $string) as $num) {
  if(!is_numeric($num)) $valid = false;
}
```

As a function:

```
function valid($string) {
  foreach(explode('-', $string) as $num) {
    if(!is_numeric($num)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I've edited the answer, because (a) `foreach ($item in $list)` is not php and (b) as long as you don't want to leave the current scope (function/method or file) `return` isn't useful.

Comment: @KingCrunch Thanks - I've been writing in too many different languages today and got confused. I think he does want it as a validation function, and there is no reason to continue the loop once $valid is false. But I'll leave it to him to do.

Comment: You can make a function out of it (would be nice too), but without it `return` can lead to confusing reactions, because you can `return` from a file (`$x = include ('fileWithReturn.php');`, which in most cases is not intended.

Comment: @KingCrunch Made a function for him.

Answer (score 1):

```
$valid = (bool) preg_match('~^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)+$~', $string);
```

http://php.net/pcre.pattern

Copied from a deleted answer by Felix Kling (see comments)

> As the others said, you can use [*regular expressions*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for this (e.g with [`preg_match` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)):

Comment: how are you related to Felix Kling? I just observed a bizarre happening

Comment: Not related, except that I can see his deleted answer below mine ;)

Comment: @prusswan: I deleted my answer because the expressions was not "good enough" ;)

Comment: nice to see that you are not clones!

Comment: @KingCrunch: I'd suggest you just copy the answer text from my answer to include some documentation :) FWIW, a single number might be valid too, then it should be `-[0-9]+)*`.

Comment: I want to see that answer too!

Comment: @Selena: Work hard until you have 10k rep ;)

Comment: The links in the comment and in my post are the same... include however you like (you don't have to reference me) but I think the links are useful in any case.